# Performance Bottleneck: How to assess the Performance of a Widget when accessed from different geographies

Tags: performance, performance-testing, ip-address, latency

I have a Page where in a specific financial widget - which is taking longer times  when accessed from a different geography where my Client team is located. Where as for me - it takes less than 2 seconds for them its more than 10 seconds
I would like to check and pin point where exactly or which component(network latency or DOM interactive etc) is the cause of the delay.

Thanks in advance.
I m using tools like Chrome Tools, Fiddler and Jmeter to evaluate test results. I want to figure out on identifying the bottleneck when accessed the Page from different countries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run JMeter test from different geographic regions, i.e. [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) allows you to create [micro instances](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2010/09/09/announcing-micro-instances-for-amazon-ec2/) at no cost and in different [regions/zones](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html) so you can compare the connect time/latency from different geolocations.

Microsoft Azure has similar conditions, [free account and $200 USD equivalent](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/) to spend on Azure services and provides [way more locations](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/geographies/)

Also there is a possibility to [run your JMeter test in distributed mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter/) so one client machine will be in EU, another in US, third one in Australia, etc. so you can compare the metrics